# How to use curtime() to check in column with now() structure? SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-date-functions

In my DB when a new user register I use `now()` for the column `date_added` (I need the exact time of registration). Also I store the user ip in column `ip`

Now I need to check in SQL if there is already registration from this ip from today

BUT

```
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer 
    WHERE ip = '" . $this->db->escape($ip) . "' 
    AND date_added = CURDATE()");

    return $query->row;
```

Does not work because I use `now()` for date_added and `now()` is not = to `curdate()`

Any ideas how to do the trick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)

```
... AND date(date_added) = CURDATE()
```

Comment: @PetarStoyanov - Arg.  Please be aware that *(afaik)* this will prevent the use of indexes so fullfil the query, resulting in a full scan.  Why not simply use `date_added >= CURDATE()`?  Your description means that you won't have any records in the future, and even if you do, just add `AND date_added < CURDATE()+1`.